# QML change image color

Tags: image, qt, colors, svg, qml

I searched for how to colorize an image (with the format svg or png ...).

I tried covering my image with a rectangle that fills the image, but as my image is not a rectangle it colorizes the whole rectangle and not just the image.

Is it possible to change image color with qml? Alternatively, is it possible to change the color on qt (with C++) with QPixmap then integrate the QPixmap on QML Item?

Thank you for your help. (If there is no solution, I will have to load a different image to the same basic image with different color.)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In **Qt 5** (from 5.2) you may use `ColorOverlay` as follows:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.0

Item {
    width: 300
    height: 300

    Image {
        id: bug
        source: "images/butterfly.png"
        sourceSize: Qt.size(parent.width, parent.height)
        smooth: true
        visible: false
    }

    ColorOverlay {
        anchors.fill: bug
        source: bug
        color: "#ff0000"  // make image like it lays under red glass 
    }
 }
```

In **Qt 6** module `QtGraphicalEffects` (which includes `ColorOverlay`) was removed because of [licensing issues](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-85256).

In **Qt 6.1** GraphicalEffects is now available again, as @SCP3008 commented below

Comment: Documentation available : [Qt ColorOverlay QML](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtgraphicaleffects-coloroverlay.html)

Comment: `ColorOverlay` does not exist in QT 6.

Comment: The entire QtGraphicalEffects module has been removed from Qt 6. They are no longer working on it and are [relicensing over to BSD](https://wiki.qt.io/Checklist_for_Qt_6.0_inclusion), ShaderEffects is likely the best workaround ATM if Qt 6 is required @AmirSaniyan

Comment: GraphicalEffects is now available again with changes in Qt 6.1 though under a different module now: [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtgraphicaleffects5-index.html) Components like ColorOverlay are modified slightly, such as not having a `samples` property anymore

Comment: Warning, I found that combining Qt5Compat.GraphicalEffects and Qt6 on TI AM335x ARM boards causing the QSGRenderThread to crash. So maybe better just find some Qt6-based solutions.

Answer (score 8):

You can replace your image color using [ShaderEffect](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-shadereffect.html#blending-prop).

```
ShaderEffect {
    property variant src: yourImage

    property real r: yourColor.r * yourColor.a
    property real g: yourColor.g * yourColor.a
    property real b: yourColor.b * yourColor.a

    width: yourImage.width
    height: yourImage.height

    vertexShader: "
        uniform highp mat4 qt_Matrix;
        attribute highp vec4 qt_Vertex;
        attribute highp vec2 qt_MultiTexCoord0;
        varying highp vec2 coord;

        void main() {
            coord = qt_MultiTexCoord0;
            gl_Position = qt_Matrix * qt_Vertex;
        }
    "

    fragmentShader: "
        varying highp vec2 coord;
        uniform sampler2D src;

        uniform lowp float r;
        uniform lowp float g;
        uniform lowp float b;

        void main() {
            lowp vec4 clr = texture2D(src, coord);
            lowp float avg = (clr.r + clr.g + clr.b) / 3.;
            gl_FragColor = vec4(r * avg, g * avg, b * avg, clr.a);
        }
    "
}
```

The above code turns your image into the grayscaled one and then applies your color.

Answer (score 7):

You can also use [Colorize](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtgraphicaleffects-colorize.html)

And the difference with ColorOverlay is:
Colorize can really change the color of a image with HSL, it is more suitable for me.
ColorOverlay is similar to what happens when a colorized glass is put on top of a grayscale image with RGBA.

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.12

Item {
    width: 300
    height: 300

    Image {
        id: bug
        source: "images/bug.jpg"
        sourceSize: Qt.size(parent.width, parent.height)
        smooth: true
        visible: false
    }

    Colorize {
        anchors.fill: bug
        source: bug
        hue: 0.0
        saturation: 0.5
        lightness: -0.2
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Work around is using `IconImage`. It has `color:`
I Found it in Qt 6.5.0

```
IconImage{
     source: "qrc:/yourImage.svg"
     color: "red"
}
```

Comment: Hi Saysdf, is that a Qt Quick control? I can't see it mentioned in the Qt 6.5 docs.

Comment: @Surfbutler As far as I know it is still not documented feature which is pretty sad as it is the best solution in terms of layout design.

Comment: Works in Qt 6.6, except that you can't use `fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit`, which can be used with the standard Image element.

Answer (score 2):

I also went looking for a non-QtGraphicalEffects solution and found a solution by using the `icon` property as follows:

- `icon.source` - for setting the SVG image
- `icon.color` - for changing the color of the SVG image
- `icon.width` - for changing the width of the SVG image
- `icon.height` - for changing the height of the SVG image

Some controls have the `icon` property such as `Button`, `ItemDelegate` and `MenuItem`.

In the following code, we implement `AppIcon` as a customized version of `Button` so that the only thing that remains is the `icon` rendering. We remove the button styling and the button size, it is clipped to just render the icon itself. Because we have customized the `Button` we can expose the `clicked` signal and the `pressed` property.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
Page {
    ColumnLayout {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        AppIcon {
            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
            icon.source: "biking-32.svg"
            icon.color: pressed ? "orange" : "red"
            onClicked: status.text = "red clicked"
        }
        AppIcon {
            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
            Layout.preferredWidth: 64
            Layout.preferredHeight: 64
            icon.source: "biking-32.svg"
            icon.color: pressed ? "orange" : "blue"
            onClicked: status.text = "blue clicked"
        }
        AppIcon {
            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
            Layout.preferredWidth: 96
            Layout.preferredHeight: 96
            icon.source: "biking-32.svg"
            icon.color: pressed ? "orange" : "green"
            onClicked: status.text = "green clicked"
        }
        Text {
            id: status
            text: "click on an image"
        }
    }
}

//AppIcon.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Item {
    id: appIcon
    implicitWidth: 32
    implicitHeight: 32
    property alias icon: btn.icon
    property alias pressed: btn.pressed
    signal clicked()
    Button {
        id: btn
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        background: Item { }
        icon.width: parent.width
        icon.height: parent.height
        onClicked: appIcon.clicked()
    }
}

//biking-32.svg
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 32 32"><path d="M16 5.5A2.5 2.5 0 1 1 18.5 8 2.498 2.498 0 0 1 16 5.5zm-1.042 19.02a1.545 1.545 0 0 0 1.021 1.688c.73.104 1.23-.25 1.452-1.211.034-.145 1.173-6.518 1.173-6.518l-3.979-2.146 2.823-4.087L19.498 15H24a1 1 0 0 0 0-2h-3.498l-2.434-3.27a1.63 1.63 0 0 0-.48-.551.995.995 0 0 0-.11-.083l-1.107-.765a1.685 1.685 0 0 0-2.194.595l-4.09 6.534a1 1 0 0 0 .367 1.408l5.114 2.8zM29.8 24.5a5.3 5.3 0 1 1-5.3-5.3 5.3 5.3 0 0 1 5.3 5.3zm-1.8 0a3.5 3.5 0 1 0-3.5 3.5 3.504 3.504 0 0 0 3.5-3.5zm-15.2 0a5.3 5.3 0 1 1-5.3-5.3 5.3 5.3 0 0 1 5.3 5.3zm-1.8 0A3.5 3.5 0 1 0 7.5 28a3.504 3.504 0 0 0 3.5-3.5z"/><path fill="none" d="M0 0h32v32H0z"/></svg>
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)