# Color overlay an image in QML (Qt6)

Tags: qt, pyqt, qml, qt6, pyqt6

In QML for Qt5 I could use ColorOverlay to apply a color to an image.

But in Qt6, it no longer exists.

What is the best way to color an image in QML for Qt6?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [QML QtGraphicalEffects is not Installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68292911/qml-qtgraphicaleffects-is-not-installed)

Comment: Qt6 still provides support for Graphics Effects, through the [`Qt5Compat.GraphicalEffects`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtgraphicaleffects5-index.html) module. Alternatively, look into [shader effects](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-shadereffect.html).

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I don't know how to install the qt5 compat module. I'm using Ubuntu Linux and I've only heard of a package on ArchLinux.

Comment: I've just noticed that you've already asked about that. I'd suggest you to look into shader effects, but in any case there is a package in experimental debian repos: https://packages.debian.org/experimental/qml6-module-qt5compat-graphicaleffects so you could *try* to install it (at your own risk). I'd also find means to submit a request to the Ubuntu repository mantainers (maybe through their irc channel or mailing list) and ask about its insertion or any suggestion.

Comment: thanks i just ended up editing the svg files directly until the feature is supported

Comment: I'm afraid you've not understood the problem: the GraphicalEffects module of Qt5Compat is not temporarily there waiting for support, it's only provided to facilitate porting for *backward* compatibility with Qt5 (hence the name), and it doesn't even include all effects. Graphical Effects will *not* be supported otherwise, they are already considered partially obsolete (due to the shader/particle system), and it's also possible that in the years to come it will be actually declared as deprecated, meaning that the module will not be updated nor made available anymore for future releases of Qt6.

Comment: Yes I understood thanks

Comment: There are ways to color an image without the need of QtGraphicalEffects. Can you tell us more about your requirements and perhaps we can provide a more concrete solution? Meanwhile, see my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/72947097/881441

Comment: Warning, I found that combining Qt5Compat.GraphicalEffects and Qt6 on TI AM335x ARM boards causing the QSGRenderThread to crash. So maybe better just find some Qt6-based solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the comments to your question and my tinkering with it, I managed to found 2 ways of colouring an image/icon in Qt 6 QML:

#### 1. [Stephen Quan's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72947097/17342313) - Simple, yet locked with centered layout

Achieved by using `icon` property of the Button class, for instance:

```
Button {
    // ... 

    icon.source:  "<IMAGE_SOURCE>"
    icon.color: "<IMAGE_COLOUR>"

    icon.width: <IMAGE_WIDTH>
    icon.height: <IMAGE_HEIGHT>

    // ...
}
```

Unfortunately, the image is centered both vertically and horizontally and it is unchangeable.

#### 2. `IconImage` class - completely layout-wise customizable

The class provides `color` property out of the box, allowing you to easily change an image colour, while also enabling you to position it however you want because it is a separate class.

The following example demonstrates how it can be used to create more complex buttons, having e.g. both a text and an image, thanks to `contentItem` property:

```
Button {
    // ...

    contentItem: Item {
        id: content

        IconImage {
            id: <IMAGE_ID>
            source: "<IMAGE_SOURCE>"
            width: <IMAGE_WIDTH>
            height: <IMAGE_HEIGHT>
            color: "<IMAGE_COLOUR>"
        }

        // ...
        // other elements classes like Text, etc. 
        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

#### Summary

As usual, there is no "the best" solution to the problem. It is up to you to decide which one you very need. The first one is the simplest to setup while the second one is the most customizable.